# How to filter rows in a Dataframe(df) where df[list] has all values less than specific float value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to return only those rows of the Data frame df, where ALL values of df[list of column names] are less than user input float value .

Note- df[list of column names] is a Data frame containing list of specific columns, that we can not hard-code.

eg..

1. First we filter specific columns start with D_BALANCE:
   cols= list(df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith("D_BALANCE ")])
2. Then we select all columns except end column (list):
   rest_except_end_col= cols[0:-1]
3. Our main master data frame is df, NOW i want to check if df[rest_except_end_col] < 1000.0 ,
   IF ALL ROWS OF THESE COLUMNS ARE LESS ONLY THEN I WANT TO GET THAT RECORD(complete row) FROM df.

Comment: `df[df[rest_except_end_col] < 1000.0]`

Comment: Thanks @IgnatiusReilly , But I tried that already and it gives me NaN values for ever column as output. Not even a single row/column has any values.

Comment: "are less than user input float", did you convert the user's input to float? Because default input is `string`. Just making sure that we know both the user input and the values in the dataframe are actually `float` and not `string`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelS. , I did convert to float if i am using user_input still it gave NaN's and even if i give hardcode value i.e.. < 1000.0 till it gave NaN's. Also all the columns df[rest_except_end_col] are of type float only. Not sure why am i not able to achieve this :(

Comment: Also, If i use  df[df[rest_except_end_col].values < 1000.0]   i get the result but all. rows comes multiple times :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df[rest_except_end_col] < 1000.0).all(axis=1)]
```

[pd.DataFrame.all()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

> Return whether all elements are True, potentially over an axis.
>
> Returns True unless there at least one element within a series or along a Dataframe axis that is False or equivalent (e.g. zero or empty).